# Why does Enumerator.new require a "yielder" object?

Tags: ruby, yield, enumerator

Consider a simple Enumerator like this:

```rb
natural_numbers = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  number = 1
  loop do
    yielder.yield number
    number += 1
  end
end
```

My question is: Why does ruby require that we invoke yield on the yielder object?  Said another way: Why can't we replace `yielder.yield number` with `yield number`?  In this example, it would be appear to be the same thing, if it were allowed.  Are there examples where yielder is used in a nontrivial way?  If so, can you give one?  If not, what is the purpose of yielder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure if that's the reason, but `yield` alone (always) applies to the block submitted to the method which calls `yield`: in your case the method which contains `natural_numbers` assignment; and it's not possible for it to perform what is desired for `Enumerator`, i.e. to emit the Enumerator element. Although bearing the same name, [`Yielder#yield`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerator/Yielder%3ayield) is a method, and Ruby's `yield` is a statement.

In other words, it would not be possible to implement `Enumerator` constructor which would work with `yield` statement.